# Unable to make connection with database from cronjob

Tags: php, cron

I have a cron.php file on my server which makes connection with the database and do some function. When I execute this file using browser, it runs perfectly. But when it executes from cron, it gives following error while making database connection:

```
ERROR: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'USER_NAME'@'localhost' (using password: YES)<br />
```

I searched a lot but no clue what to do. Any ideas?

EDIT: Basically, this is my cron.php:

```
<?php 
require_once('phpInclude/db_connection.php');
error_reporting(1);
$sql_qry = "select email, apn_id, reg_id, token from users where verify = 'n' and DATEDIFF(NOW(),created_on) = 3";
$res=$con->query($sql_qry);
?>
```

My db_connection.php:

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');
try {

    $dsn = 'mysql:host='.$DB_HOST.';dbname='.$DB_DATABASE;

   $con = new PDO($dsn, $DB_USER, $DB_PASSWORD);
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


    } 
    catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
$DB_HOST = LOCALHOST;
$DB_DATABASE = DB_NAME;
$DB_USER = USER_NAME;
$DB_PASSWORD = USER_PASS;
?>
```

My config.php:

```
    define('LOCALHOST','localhost');
    define('USER_NAME','xxxxxxxxxxx');
    define('USER_PASS','xxxxxxxxxx');
    define('DB_NAME','xxxxxxxxxx');
    define("UPLOAD_PATH","xxxxxxxxxxxx");
    define("BASE_PATH","xxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
```

Comment: none. we don't know what your db username and/or password are.

Comment: i think your password not match.. check it again

Comment: @MarcB with due respect, I am just asking for what the scenario it may be that I am getting this error.

Comment: that is the scenario. you're not using the proper credentials. wrong username, wrong password, and/or wrong hostname.

Comment: @Harshana It works when I execute this php file from browser using its full url.

Comment: @MarcB Then how it is working when I execute it from browser?

Comment: @MarcB I made a lot of web services from same config, and all work fine. This config also works when I execute this php file manually from browser. But it is giving me this error when it got exedcuted from cron.

Comment: cron is a completely different operational environment than when running under a webserver. obviously SOMETHING is different. but since you haven't shown any code, we can't help you.

Comment: Can you add the code for cron.php (remove username/password, obviously)?

Comment: @versalle88 ok posting..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. I was having a localhost check in my config.php file. At first, I made the webservices at localhost using wamp, so the config was of localhost. Later, I moved the project on my server. And I changed the config by adding:

```
if(server="http://myserver.com")
    //take server config
else
    //take localhost config
```

And cron service picked the config inside else clause.

Answer (score 0):

CRONs typically run from the CLI, so it may not be accessing this file from the webroot like when you browse to cron.php. Try changing the require to an absolute path:

```
require_once __DIR__ . 'phpInclude/db_connection.php';
```

Comment: Even tho if that was the case, I guess it must have returned error at required_once i.e. file not found.